# Disable a widget in kivy without darkening its color

Tags: kivy

My app has a button which disables two other buttons (in the same gridlayout) on `on_press` event.
I don't want my buttons to turn dark after they are disabled, I want them to keep the original color.

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial



Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: "press me to disable button 1 and button 2"
            on_press: root.val0()
        GridLayout:
            id:w_101
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "button 1"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color:(0.988, 0.53, 0.0, 1.0)
            Button:
                text: "button 2"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color:(0.988, 0.53, 0.0, 1.0)

""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val0(self):
        self.ids['w_101'].disabled=True

sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I cannot find any property in gridlayout which does not apply dark color to a disabled item. 
This is not working:

```
self.ids['w_101'].background_normal=''
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

When a widget is disabled, sometimes it changes its background *image* as the Button does. You already have `background_normal` set, but you need to set it for disabled Button too, therefore the answer is right in your kv file:

```
Button:
    text: "button 1"
    background_normal: ''
    background_disabled_normal: self.background_normal ## This
    background_color:(0.988, 0.53, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `disabled_color` property of the button.

Comment: No, it is not working. Infact, no change. Please help.

Comment: disabled_color is the color of the text, if disabled